# Fuseki indexed (Lucene) text search returns no results

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, owl, fuseki

I have a very large ontology RDF file (almost 4M instances) that I'm currently streaming via Fuseki v2.0.0. My assembler file looks like this:

```
@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix text:    <http://jena.apache.org/text#> .
@prefix myprefix: <http://www.example.org/some/path/myprefix#> .

## Example of a TDB dataset and text index
## Initialize TDB
[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .
tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
tdb:GraphTDB    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

## Initialize text query
[] ja:loadClass       "org.apache.jena.query.text.TextQuery" .
# A TextDataset is a regular dataset with a text index.
text:TextDataset      rdfs:subClassOf   ja:RDFDataset .
# Lucene index
text:TextIndexLucene  rdfs:subClassOf   text:TextIndex .
# Solr index
text:TextIndexSolr    rdfs:subClassOf   text:TextIndex .

## ---------------------------------------------------------------
## This URI must be fixed - it's used to assemble the text dataset.

:text_dataset rdf:type     text:TextDataset ;
    text:dataset   <#dataset> ;
    text:index     <#indexLucene> ;
    .

# A TDB datset used for RDF storage
<#dataset> rdf:type      tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "DB" ;
    tdb:unionDefaultGraph true ; # Optional
    .

# Text index description
<#indexLucene> a text:TextIndexLucene ;
    text:directory <file:Lucene> ;
    ##text:directory "mem" ;
    text:entityMap <#entMap> ;
    .

# Mapping in the index
# URI stored in field "uri"
# myprefix:foo is mapped to field "text"
<#entMap> a text:EntityMap ;
    text:entityField      "uri" ;
    text:defaultField     "text" ;
    text:map (
         [ text:field "text" ; text:predicate myprefix:foo ]
         ) .
```

In order to perform text searches on a particular element within a reasonable response time, I imported the RDF file using text indexing:

```
$ java -cp $FUSEKI_HOME/fuseki-server.jar tdb.tdbloader --tdb=run/text-config.ttl ontologies.rdf
```

... and

```
$ java -cp $FUSEKI_HOME/fuseki-server.jar jena.textindexer --desc=run/text-config.ttl
```

... then running the Fuseki server as

```
./fuseki-server -v --debug -loc=DB /dataset
```

No errors during the import, and I can run various SPARQL queries against this new dataset with no issues. But when I try to perform a full-text query, I get 0 results:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix myprefix: <http://www.example.org/some/path/myprefix#>

SELECT ?s ?sci_name
{ ?s text:query (myprefix:foo '123test' 10) ; 
    myprefix:foo ?sci_name 
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I see no warnings or errors on the Fuseki server logs, even with the verbose and debug flags set. I can perform a regular SPARQL query to get these same results, but it's (understandably) quite slow:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix myprefix: <http://www.example.org/some/path/myprefix#>

SELECT ?s
{ ?s myprefix:foo ?o .
  FILTER regex(str(?o), "123test", "i")
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated, as I'm new to Fuseki/Jena and I'm hitting a dead end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the server with

```
./fuseki-server -v --debug -loc=DB /dataset
```

then it is not using your configuration file.  Try:

```
./fuseki-server --desc text-config.ttl
```

or better have a Fuseki configuration file with service and dataset description (see examples) and run:

```
./fuseki-server --confg config.ttl
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andy. I assumed (incorrectly) that since the TDB directory was being specified in the assembler file it would configure everything that's needed there. I incorporated the Fuseki service into this file and used it to start the server, worked like a charm.